# error opening dompdf in new tab

Tags: pdf, twig, dompdf, slim

I have downloading PDF's and PDF downloading with the opening of a new tab using _blank in the link
both download fine
However

I am trying to get ***"Attachment"=>0)*** so that is opens in the tab
this now leads to a page of text that has not rendered as a PDF

Using SLIM and TWIG I have the following

```
$html = $twig->render('reportPdfView.html', array(
            'pageTitle' => 'Report Detail',
            'report' => $reportShowResult,
            'users' => $userList
            ));
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render(); 
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0));
```

in response to question what do I see -

```
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R 13 0 R 17 0 R 21 0 R 23 0 R ] /Count 5 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R /F3 10 0 R >> /XObject << /I1 11 0 R /I2 12 0 R /I3 15 0 R /I4 16 0 R /I5 19 0 R /I6 20 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageC ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate (D:20140208210105+00'00') /ModDate (D:20140208210105+00'00') /Title (Trainers Report) >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Length 1534 >> stream 1.000 1.000 1.000 rg 34.016 34.016 543.969 723.969 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 34.766 713.165 Td /F1 28.5 Tf [(Attendance List)] TJ ET q 180.000 0 0 61.500 397.234 695.734 cm /I2 Do Q BT 34.016 682.774 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(ID: 26 - )] TJ ET BT 71.364 682.774 Td /F2 10.5 Tf [(Sun 29th September 2013)] TJ ET BT 193.941 682.774 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [( - Trainer: des cooke )] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 34.016 652.459 222.028 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 40.016 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Name)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 256.044 652.459 166.521 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 262.044 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(House)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 422.565 652.459 38.855 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 428.565 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Day1)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 461.420 652.459 38.855 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 467.420 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Day2)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 500.274 652.459 38.855 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 506.274 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Day3)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 539.129 652.459 38.855 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 545.129 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Cert)] TJ ET BT 34.016 625.249 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(Key:)] TJ ET 0.933 0.933 0.933 rg 0.933 0.933 0.933 RG 34.016 607.197 m 577.984 607.197 l 577.984 606.447 l 34.016 606.447 l f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 34.016 579.237 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(Days Y -Attended, N -Absent, am -attended am, pm -attended pm )] TJ ET BT 34.016 563.974 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(Certtificates C -completed, A -attended, N -no certificate)] TJ ET endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Oblique /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F3 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 11 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 240 /Height 82 /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms << /Predictor 15 /Colors 1 /Columns 240 /BitsPerComponent 8>> /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 5494>> stream xœí\dríÿŸãH’$I’$I’$É$I’ÌL&3If&33“ÉÌd233™™™I2333“™ÉÌÌ$3ÉL2I’Iff’$ù\çW?Î9ÝÏžÏó}¾÷ãyýqßwç¼¯¯ëÇû×u{hè_ü‹ñ/þ@·|•É—+ŸïÅìÝ’ðïîÍ_ŒñÈk»¥mÖßÝ©¿ "ï}›Á¿»gØ¦z¶ª|èïîßÿŒÓÁl´xðßÝÅÿ%ÅÖ¯ùþ³ksÄÁÕü×/kÅ_Û†èú'tl¬Á=`ø×ExÀ$PKÀL¨ŠÉ€ÕÕ©å×£õú/¸;Žs?¤Ûn?°™´­hBSv¥˜Ãb!¥mŸÇãD"1<³[‚i¾B·NrIÍã°™”ª˜Ó7ëÑi”2>‹*ÐC(U*å¤;07ÍÇ†‘_ì'Õlþb3«8ôÛø}{,òØL]7m™ ŸCÐõ<¯;%N?#æy_Ém±€CÛÔ,¿ÅD, ;a§„ù  H=øúúú®ÕH‡E´‹ráï?WD"P+E² |0¬’p1yÒBûrÊìžáM‘JFŒj¢d?¦?q‰‚Q'²á5ügÖ~rÉ|«•÷÷Jõã»Ö¤ë_JÆ¥›bXÞ‘¨.KÁ:%w¢­®Ý¾ð8´"”yäÛ‹f¥E´¦ù"¿¾šÑ‰Ù”ÞÈÞ:×3ã&9ÅÇ'oüT¬’jù,åÒO©§L¶ðþY£é_Y#¤ÛÅ° G&mWˆ¸ÌþžÀ”    Â‘ÍØ<ÉÞ$–=&—•·PK>mÎÚ•<©'‰‹­E§VÈæ×±ŸÑÍ…±%R%õüÓÍY,;ß=¿½SµÝþ6I©ƒ øpû¤–u2>»oÿAð=áÜÑê„VƒÜÒõTÍÇ–Š”¦dá$4©–ÒY¯ÄÃéºÇ âð±™k$ŽBäõÜÊ=œî¬.Î/Ö÷NéÂg›ŒúˆŠ2¨N¿Ø¹E-êÓ(|N©EéjkÊV äÃ4k5d   ¶²Ç«ã¶žª4%ßov¦‡Eýë­•¼¢lF¸–¾Ü"ï«êÃqhÆi5[®™•½‹Ç,eã}MPåÃ&É½ÙtnOg 'Ü¨}||T>¿Áïòuí6t„½ÿ®‚€4*ÈÜF–ÑEêˆtêý®”K…|’ÊížÏØGzëïDánwÚ dq1Âõ—8%.Jž®y,j™D*×˜œ³GwE²D‰2¨ô„Ûï£Ã2^W²Cøû£üö’~Æ~m.6½ÈÃxg¾*o©Äe<¸:Z÷%èþa&£V)^Ÿnoo“Ÿíb}6:ÂÅ)K‡ñ Â±½·QÊ “xv·=ã0†‡Q§)K¨èjùåfÙm7ê´z£mÌårè¥=Ž>­­·B¶DÞv÷¦ÆúóÖn K¨$’û$=A"Ü¨^òé°ûØ \;Ùõi% sðg­ƒY›F.y,Ô²A&üEåí.²ä–‹H¦ÒêÔ²îžºÄ¥ò…×{œZ>ÑK¸Q 4Ÿöôî   ˜+³øûJ7Û½àW„‹Ï7g]‹{á1J1ïoáz|ó`Ž¾ótk\/pYL<¸Á…zéù4èÒK¸,ƒÁdsB Ó1öF¼ì{áõîèžŽpýÚüˆºÇÈB,‘>Ô?™ó SE— ×³‰Èfh§³¬7'btÍ ÜHÌ[eˆhm·óøpD+æv"‡(öð#·ë3K1ó´ƒÙšU0¡¯BîáhíœŽp£Bm?¨èÙS Jö¾mîæ-´žA¸–>ß˜õL/>Ú§ß©AµB‡p³  ñ'ŽÒõî¬YÊF|u·µK»VÜq\ðÌÓûëeh\ÝÕR}i‚y¼`1Ÿ: y#´„ËTÂï¢~Â#}³Q~>¿ƒÎ—î~:Œ›ÍÎÂ˜·+‘>v³Ï©ä#‚‡û«ØšÛ€`0Gfíšý;‡NBlœp9}¼d—Ñ‡§„Æ{/¤ã[ÓÖ0-aŠSŒlÏôA,NŸ^k5*[f m´Ô!œŠ-ÚÔ ­ƒJZÛSfD„[ÕÂÓÍiìÅÁ~xut|5£Ým–vê‰à·¥T„Þ ðà­³wvõ:=aº€m¿»‡aÖ.@DC×`—ptÞ,ˆT¶=\þmuBu‡p)ß.ÎÍø|3^—UC„x0[lp•: e]TáA>_åÇ­›ŠâeÊ…ÔÉê¸V¤%\¦ †€j52¦éÞkÍÿ5a“„Ã¨¬„Y´Ë‘Žã„ßî—&íf#ŠaƒF!â¦šÁ•™=ÝE•s #Œ!xïÙ`ÂfL¢U|ž¹QÊ[¥%\¢ÙÄ &¬–5ú×_³,¡zNocÌN8{³å5)%"B>·›˜<àÝÝušIŽ£ŒVìgãñ`–Ö  J`ïùd,0¢ä±Wh    óõ„j¥—øÁÓ@¾íöý9¡ÑO‚Ù"mŽùÈã„U«°™8pOØ1ù ³§ëâ_L$&Sƒÿ|ŠÒ»yCx0Þ*½^oy "6s™žðÚúžIŒû    £Ž“ÄˆëˆûM7²‹qÂ/Á1%²R!ˆš€Œåfw7rÞréÅl‘MÉ/Ùdl¯g {ÿ]H-9\ƒžpá5K ðŠ«þ ˜LlHžâ{Vˆ, k—ð¨b@ê]Õr“ûhåË?¦r8iìWå+š¢¸Å+çá©a@ø-Îu=ý?o‡LqÅq_±~¾æþÂùO#Œ¥ÃÛD+÷ó6…€7‰ÿJl¹u|šô6oÍbúl8‚L˜A»‡ë¹ÔÃsñ¿g,ïËàPGB‚o™Û)ƒˆù£Fs¥†qbÿ7·¦Œ2¡ß¹Ã9³„º¦ùxÛ…dtÁ¦à±˜lZ-]}¸¾Í”)1âOëMÅÒ†˜B\yf¢ˆCú³F­“D?†gÒÛ÷+N­DLDî«cxÒ§·îu4kÅ—äíÍõõuŽ–ðKâô4ñRþ”soÕ¾B îóÊ(„A´El¥³•÷§„cŽDOµæžÏ¢”â;°²”T4i‰p&~¸½N?¾ëÍf‹Jíë9h_!gð»=ìÏx<Ÿ†|ÓÑøc&W¤œ2|U ÙL:ÉæKÕ/zE/ìæèhÁ"ìáçÝî”Aø'#FMŽç¥ŠG1”8k·6ÜÀé/>Ð >Y™°xü›‡g×²ìwéå!~z||z™HfòZ·{CÞ“¢#Œ{û3Ã¢?C1j¸¢þº\wë%’ÎÁbku\'êßÆ4=>XdÂQ½fØáž[= ‹6‹ÏW‡+KKËkÛ‘ó»Láƒ¦¾{m7)IKx'¼~ãŸ#Œ®ñj‰ðŒI*”wIš«£Èé[W}àf¸Õj6êµÚ7"/M"âi¥X¬Ð[”1*=]„'Gm6‡Ó3Ü;ÈÑÌñ›©ãÙÒ^ÀVÿ4aˆµ…®ßï£ÆªŽ‰f[Û#€q7äÂOR¾ªÅlæù)•zz¢ÏZÂ69Ã+ƒ”    ÎÄÃócµ\®PlóÇ÷Y*á’½³¦i   ê³üø“%ÝïXC<W{Œ,Úd\®ÄØ½,wl×Š;š‹ ü]yKÝœŸ§öÛ¤“+¡d ‰ýÅQ­„Ïåpù"¹Î>ŒÝQõ»SÍûa¼'íÂýÞô*­õe‰º3Œ7ò™Œúm2‹¯°uÓ!on½Oâv’g»k?ÀÒÕ`ÂÀÓæPN¢ÛÉØ²,&ÃW¨4¹ƒGÔ4vÙ­0†¢Ø³æÛmØ£üš°¬Ýv ÜŽ÷©‰QM‚–²A„­éÉ³n›”BìFAøãå*YÃ=”f²c |5~ÜîxÁþçýá5áv;Î#fSÌðëåÚxÇñ"ß÷ÂzüQÊÞÇ‚zà  š7–ºÜíS=¹Ú{áù2ì³v¯ ŒÙÀ+p-lœâýÉ]unæ<-ZñÅn„iz!“|7‹‹Œþ=¼BxOÅí2"lQPkhÖªÅ·t"ºê1;5T¢JxºØ] „bé>uT¯³çÛsv•€Õ£?WÀ“jmž¥­ØC PÍÆ;û¡.Ú¡Žc‘B®-QÍ.=ãÞ   †äUQ{CS¢ÄØ³yJ‡ÿ0‘Éåóù7Ùìk&u{¶˜@o}cöíÄŸ^Á«\^ŸÑ5Ÿgfi+Ï”¿jõz£‚ñükê:¶îs¨…¤nÀ å‡×¿9»Ï?oÎygCÇ÷éçÄðÐÕÏÜgéd|ô‘'PÚöož³hÓo ¾§ßÓg=GH•Ô,#º·{G æHÍÓëÑ‹ë×W—g± oÌ€Ü^‚ –È0¹²zyEFüì0ä5[F½þƒ“øíCê „<·—±í%·E%¤G;Ë)v÷|0¼¿¿éw{üÛGçÑuDŸÃh:_3æß9¹8Ý_vé„®Ôä];<‹#­]ßÜ¥²Î˜Ú+¼¡¶YÍ^÷åÓ`–H;:³ÚØì`}myaÊiV‹ÑûiÈéºÍ³¸Z'#´ºèµëär•Á>9…÷£±££èA8ä÷Žä|]`_®³8½³s3.»Õ19¿ZÌ€@Gò%æÉ…ÕPÐï±*ùlŽHã˜Z ¢MolíÝdj±ú¡Ì3EA7?óÿˆ²Ïû”é¬c®‰‰I.çˆÅ –ò±È,D±Úäwõc||ÌnTÀŒ'’kM—Ç7·è_œ÷yÇí¥ˆ;à8BY UéÍV³A£Ö™ìN×ø(ðA°Ë0[¤2:œãÎ“xçÈ®78±–Ý3+7í =_ÅÔ   ¢{»Þ'¢KD2¥Z­Á¡V«”r)r]ï1Ää¤ ¥Š ¥¹ Î`°8|±\­6[¬³Q¯–‰¨·{¶2Ìdó„©T,Š¤ •Z­°;¼`tðH¥"!ð  j­Ùˆ>ü©ó‡Ægñé|sª{µßX,—×.—Ãî½u1Xl·O¤+‡~zÆá   Db‰T" xœÁtqÎ&¨DXË\¤Ôi‹x„^³CšÆšHB»üÑ'-ZuÀ÷bÛgSL5åû òWø·Œ>ôÉ!€ˆwXL&üÇÐ`Ÿ{ 0 ê :‘–ˆGÝ¦Â“Û#IºýôÖªùÔùÖ,bÿ°Cÿ hQÿ—õ3…z÷æÕëû×šõ¯÷ìýÉ†Ï®Ò©Ïß0WáðGrŒØl|Wé›èÚ”õ÷å‹Ü€3x6ã/•?)šÍFí³œK^ì/»-Jûÿàµ¿ QØç÷osÕGHØÜ6êÝ§ëØÆÜØ0âü®|ÑS ­s9vÿV¥ÿp§ÕjÔëµï@÷æ8¼ä±iÄƒÜß0G2<<ºÏU¾©g£-0¹µïÏJá5y}^žÞž€æ;¬ß hvÌŒ&2Åêw½Ñ9*nµ¶¥\úøòéQã`oï7â›&—÷._‹ä¼Þ@€œL}Vß¹ôãõÉþú¢gÄ¨¢ùæìwÂØàœ[ÄÒ¹Bé½Zý¨V+ïåb>—IÝÅO6—}.›^)¦ûªð·ÄäJ4ÖÉÅõ}>>¥3//™ôSò>?î®|“#&LÈe1~WãKÄ`äzÛ„/°>ˆŸœžžÇ÷¶CËóS.‡I«ó‘“œÆô¢@ÒBz}þÀòrÀ??;í1­F.æsYƒ¿Øþ](£©Þh±Ù»Õb4èT ¦åsþlQ©D*“Ëe (òyXLûOd‹‰•™ ªFÁÂ.÷þcÉÀþGø§1é®‚Ö~ endstream endobj 12 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 240 /Height 82 /SMask 11 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms << /Predictor 15 /Colors 3 /Columns 240 /BitsPerComponent 8>> /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 6214>> stream xœíy˜ÅùÇ¿U}ÌtÏìÁî²,Ç²°ÜQTLx*D#ü¢B¨`ÂåÊ%ñ<¸5b~êÅpŠþ!Š–ÕeÙåX`wçè£~Œ;OÏÝÓÓƒ˜ôç™ÇGz«»ª«ßzë­·ÞªÎOAÈv$Û8ü—Àó¼ªª¡ÿoSZÚµk×òöå-JJŠŠŠšåçË^/G)cŒâóûÏœ>]Ss¬âpÅ®]»vìø¥T×õÌ‹á´CFBcJZ¶ìÒ¹Ëå?¾ü¢‹.¦”*Š¢iZÊÛA ”nxíµÍ›6ž:u*?¿Y]Ý©ŒÊ“ÉÍ………?ýiÿ›‡ “$)Z~ŽÇãY·î™×7lj!ÖpÚÁ Ç]sÍµcùË°†¶…ÚÚÚ)“'eòG Ò£¤¤åÔiÓZ·nÍó¼¢¦®®î×wO„U=í´ƒÀz_ØgôèQ¥¥mu]Ï†(‡ùlçÎ'Ÿ|ÂÚ½¼½Eqø#ä|èÞ£û˜1cËËËMõ2äâ¾}ËÚµ«8|ØÂ½Ž†vHFAAÁ„‰/ºèâ@ ( c¬¢¢`„P¯×[XX(‚ªª™hñššš©S&[¸ñ¿KCË @PFd±ßü ÿ¿™4IQ”$Ò¬(Ê3¦=zÔx±¬¬lØðáÝ»÷eÙšX·iÓ¦]»v‡ÓWÒñ5ô H•Ð?…º ºY1—@3{‚³òHá&BŒj¾°Ú2+¡gòŽh z5¸2Ð ðu`*p¬ ú·`Ðë²Ó~À=Áµá€ÍÐÔxÑx;‘õÀóüSO/*..Nž5clÜ¯n÷ûý‰Ü0dèÈ‘# ±blØðÚË/½”î]ñs ~:\¡ÿ÷Õ‚-FðÓ„¯o…Ÿ€{îL¦†þu1jŽ0m@×Ar'þÐûŸ[à_¡šÏ½äXkÐ…pµu5=Ÿkä¨óL”6-®ÿ9 î¦+UÐo/nâ'á¾œ±À¡1*!¤°¨pÉ’e”¦P8ª¢ÜqÇø$Ê;„ËåZ¼di~~~òd±TUUÝwï=éÞ¿ÐAc@èç)]÷kÇBL7ƒDì….€è€å_JuGö †äJœ8ôŽ9 ³áöšQPàØ"¸_ÔTh*O8ïg#c l†ü\EMm)ôû UÄIdÎŽ×ÀºvíºhñÒ”ÒL)>ýþ”Ò Ü=qÂÁÿ;eÊ(:tèî-H$ÐJÌ(¹ÂfÈWÚay×e¨’RútàQ¸ÌH¦ÂWoNêàÙùbpæUº]£ïb?Aš1$ê3qÀ¡ÄýUÌŸöÇ\)-m;ã™f¤ùoo¼Q]]m¾Øóæ=ä7!ýQäxsÒ½%~ÑÕŠä€Ì‡kÜ9£ÚH"&~iÑ´38ã €þ   ´ÐªÁø¦‹ÿ€¶ÝœAEÈK bŠC |\HýÁ½ OhÜ†Däfº±0 ™ØårMŸ1$u±}>ß³Ï®3WäïPUõÉ…9ŽKÔ/¤­:­èÚ ÐÜ›GÃw0±JH‰±:9à3#3/"¹&¤åz~C&0¾#†_îa¸O€=ˆ„Ãš(t`5ÜžÈÜ)Ð¶úËPöBÓ    ¤'¸kÁõ—’¡½AŒƒx„³†7 ™Æ¢¤¥­‚òÀƒ3yžOY­„×^{5|¾cÿþ}õõõ’$™LO9u*í@%ëÆƒ <é)^Og,•7ÈTøÌ?¨-è T…o)Ië¡‰l~Û¡ FC^:št\e Æ§P`=”•ˆˆËiÛ u+TùÀRH™hkÜñçŒypÀZ(¹À0ØdÜ§OI–(G    MÑº\î|ðµ\V¯^5uê4“‰«ªª,daJ Cï«fp?\]Á-´{üž’#Ð× ElW”Û™„Ä|¯ƒä"…ëò˜  û$jÞäzðË¬3Y7‰lØ"\šÆ<—‚ef ìƒ~gßœ5:vìŽr„Ð”ínÿ¾/,gLFç¹ÝîwÞyÛB¦Zv@Û_gÐ)û‚3 ¯ ô·î2é°×á1™X.E}ÊÌB¿Ðày½\7ÐØ¡½Ix w¤÷ØV;Ì­$4YÉ×Ô(°ÚÄÌtG,Ý{t§G(!„¤ÖÖ·œ‘ù5)Û·o¯¬¬´Ez³u_Aÿ5ü3í€Q+À…çb,@˜É_£¹ÉËW ¸ ÿôË`zHC.ˆ±õS`’Ý‚e$ÀóipºíÒìõz§IsjdëUˆ”Á„•¿_a1÷¼ õ:4œˆTu0üÐó)8ä[°÷"íð"dkOûYäØë$Xuž”ÔÝ—qÀ€1¶Z!¼^/Ó ¥õ¢CÇŽ–óE—{cúý÷544XËÂb<… ÜßèQ50®^HÏ×˜Už@ j4V²É’L÷¬«ãYlºÜ/ÚA¦Áw\ž!n·;­ø¡Î;›T´±”—·Ož€ã¸5øƒ5c#„õ!Œƒïÿ åW~waú#z T@?lúgòÔ‚ÝTirAþÙüDwˆ®†ºâ€Ïll‰e&\F»n”YÎÑ$~ _¿~ÖfÆ¿#É_].×êU«¶n}×jÑ€ÌÃGg!°¤¯a´¤OÀ=.ÍÎQ¹-ý)€­P_    ÑØd-ï€ïKÓfƒ$,a¨È¦†ž¡$<Þ€u©|”–   ©\Jèºvë­#¶mÛ–V.„6mÚ‡·:ˆBÅyóÚ³{wZ%ÃN¸þŠH±øèè4½ý,›¡Ù+¡¼Ù“„XéÇV ¤¬jËaŸ}|±Ñ5vÑØØHizê¶¸¤Åˆ#Óº…1vç]Is0œ÷ÐÜÃ‡I’;nóØ E˜ÿ_!‡U–Üñ…81Nß" ‚ …`ÄF`)¤¹ðo1á}‹J‘½æ7 ¢ÛNslw6GŸ§OŸ654 ©ÚÍÃ†}ñÅÞÝ»w›ô+8¨K—.‰Úår=üÈ£¤‰ŠŠŠ;w~òñÇG**ÎÖŸM«l6hhœ»>c­ˆÀRdÚÚìe‚ëŒzáF°¹p 7ÑŸ}h™…Õká†i˜o,h/‡J÷EQfÎš=èºëÌHsiié]ªgŒ1¿ßïóùŠŠŠ8{ÎœuÏ=÷øüyyiÄRÛ Ð!öAÿÂÐ3à‚óÉÝb-”yD)× 0â]©æÿe0šu »}U†‚36”Jè‡³©žCìß·ÏÂ¢]×ÇŽ»îÙçŠš7O’¬eËVó,49c,¶k×nåªU¿[þ{·Û”~´ó«L‚ßhdðÀì¦Z²ÄÛPï†/ªX¸ ÂMIõôg‘Íµ$ à1C·&Ïfm,häøñã'OYÏp¹\Ë—¯øÝòÃ†¤ëßÀÓ‹Yvó…),,XûÇg®¾úš”)ã·Ë<gíWÐÇ›sAÜñÆÈój4ú8Þ‚'üõ< —¢>»óÈº‚®ƒeã»€Iðœ`¼Wòª¡N|ñÖ/eZ¼9\  À`¤˜_¸b¸ Àt>H<xžð÷fÀ4„?Œ×ë¿`¡Çë‘¤;HpÇq|]Ý©S§N5Ô×‚·Kêö£nI,taó¦MÉC±mV3O"hìZ4 ýy¹SÂ¿ ßÓÒÀï µHàÄ:f”t/H[k}Á?þ{Y1R__ÿÂÏg¢J5M²,·nÝºs—.={^Ð©s'¥€¢(72jÔh‰l$ûûÍÐŒYÝnß2D{9 v#OGË4{ î¸Š¹ÄC´Û nð¸3¾ùèŸ½ü¿/Y[¡}ÎPeèÏ~Ö«W¯DƒQûz=£_s>EwDánEcTù:€ÞÏ˜fÀ&¨ÔðÏî Öãtbð€üÈ0ŒÖ€Ýç|jpË–ÍS§LN²-Áù€®ëÎœåñÄÍ´_ wA3zƒ`m³3~²…`<|FùU  F‡Ë4ª ü«EBt5öo[õ¦¶¶vü¯nŸ1}zmm Çq*lBÈ'üÏ?Ü»gÏ±c5¢(fþLº®O¼ûî¸ÊŠúÜí’&e£-AŽd#›Ø}-”±Ñô€Üqu<Ãaèe†ö9âëPOÛ1 Þ43G¥TWWßß½IvvaàÀAãÆ·lálÙ²å…?=u1+ÆÀ7Ðs*mÎKG‡X‹ ±”HÜÓ]Ð÷DêÎAà¯°c É¨øÐ´¸ð¯g‚_ìn ÙcÀ€+gÍžmFškjjî½gZò}JEÙ¼yÓˆ[o9RQaÍ»rÃ ×Ç^ÌŠ@3~aÏy/ÐÖA1V?âÎ³`)‚Fï†xîLÖÀ†ÈÆ\ºüäŠ+&Lœhf/]BÈÜ9³MÚ@àf|±w¯™±k·nQ³"ÐQ+IÓÚ'à{äld?0ÞƒŸCÛÓ­?LEçñÐ¹wïÞ“'O1c7BæÌžuæÌ™´žÿÈ#8p ÝRƒÁz^uñ\Tâ©È®µQ†pÇÄ•ó$Q.è /Y]Ü…˜±9¸ÍýÎA¸L³fÍfÏ™krŠ¤²²òë¯¿¶ËsÆLíÚG/ÉŠ—£ÄØ–(Û0k¹7 I0S[à{Rø#3 ÈzÈ£,Í‡K‘ù®Fð9sÁ·Ó þÜ>×a\fÎœeòx+ÆØÃ¿g5öÌ33flZ~ââè¸¨¬hè¶ FS«ê"ÐÍÒñ‚†>?2•¥ ‚äJ}’7R ÍëÝl÷°7«ÑØØ`yq+€wÞ~ÇüFa!bwsÌJ…ô2<–•Ù€´)RµTò½Ê&(Q}\è_ —œ«aC¶UÅM7Þ¤(¦ú JéÆ39†"|øáö´n¡1»?Ú/ÐèkP1pôÜjhË¯ea¢.@ð}hQ•š²òåç_8xº\zée¹yy&SJÿþÖ[æøþ{ï§•¾±1ÚÀ³_ €Ëè(' çXCë€¤Eš:²¨Ñ½H€æ¬Øá32@X÷JHço ‹    ÆoôÓ%ß¿=´ä$Ã«ªªÒšÝeÏfÎ¹¼ñmÏMˆz˜Ð# ¿¹ÄÜjæÐi/«!›üÝt4ÅÃð¯D0J!‡¢—Þ„gôùo˜ABÝ`Œ1Æ¦iš®ëº®‡/…Ñí8îMU•´– W‰ª°S %àåH± ÀKçv©,fÁ’ õû¥ê÷)À€ypE©ÒZ°´Êý"”)ðÇŽh`"„M§A<¿–X¦"´äI×4JICCý‚§ž¼mäH¿ÏTEQTUgÌ¸%›-f%ÇqæÏ¨a×®]QMu‰)s ÀhwCT"/î‚~Òô99\Àkmæ"pƒÁ‡þ-‹á~ÚJ­ÌË™×%àŒê…&¥¿IÈ§Ð®Gãr¸K#wØ×€\aF@øú~è•Ð·Býæûvþ$Ï^ÊÉy}ÓÆÚ“'÷} Ù¡Ã·BÜCÉÙ³g9žxAEQÀó´ÉDeënø0…EEæ‡•º®ïÜ¹#ê¢)n2b¬S–… @û€úbNfQÓ‹Ø]tDæ÷å$ ¤hpgÁBMdÜÆb€~à®„ôôPÿ ý,X€bkÀßÞ¹Él†ZmIÚjÁnoÄhdáuÀ”–rÀI°oM8¶bÏw6m¾?»ªZé¥Wû‚{œÏYP×ÖŠ¢(É²,Ë„J)        ½z÷þñk¯Æ9HÀ”@€ŒIê½õ=R`Zª}2æŽŒJßÖ½É+UDì‡þxfÑs«|Á:ƒÆ••ØAUÔ¼c‘%¯Cóï¡NÕdâ@È³ÎØÑê£²,çææ^àž›¢iÚ¨Q£2èÁƒ¯3|'Â[o¾{=¾ áØ\æ!°#UD¯…-ð’3ä P€  &PK_¦(›?0¾ëÑ˜HÓG½yWPãi™M»üŒAQzª*Í|ÅØÑªªÚÚÚ3gNû}ª¢ê,âû–%-yÞºìôêÝÛ¤ÏÀsÏ=w¥z|6s$O\ànBãÛ©Lâ¼ˆýúíá,Ø(ønFã¿ §«íy`-‚¶H³±<¿@ã4¾Õ“tô~U“ÝâBÓÝÞðu ]âQ~—È£a¬QS[[WW×Pßu]‹²w9žŸ2uªå‡9ÊL4MÓ¶lÞ÷OñÛÓ¯FœHÈíÅ|m‚‰¶ˆ¢¨žñQ…ˆ§hƒÝ   _   ÈµàÇA”@b«”2ÈPV!X™ÛõØ|– ÐÜ(W€Wb2êÎXèúu*ÿ½èÎ¸ ‰WgÿüóD ~‘Êß…….ñ;Ã›R*ŠBnnnq‹­[·nÝºMóâæ99¹.QŒÍw¹\Í»wï3¹PJW®Z““úÐXŽãþ°zuòÃ„~ðñÙCSÕòòrÇãÍñæäääååæçå7+((((ÈËËóx=.—Ès|ìdµ¦iW^uUYYÙg»v©I­A–,]fòhûÅ‹ŸNyD¢£¡’qíµ×†vÀ „ò<ç–¤œœœfÍ š5kæÍñJn‰çã´‘;v¬X±_#€¢¢¢!C†¦<ý›PòÍ‘Ê9sf›ôOÿ £Á²ÎÁƒ}~YYBÇq¼À‹¢(ÏóÔÄ¶Ž!×ž,Ë²,—””„Õ9c,å"EŽã–.]º}Û?ÌØÑÐ)ÈÏËzÉbMÓHhº›r”RJ)gòhCH’ôî»ï>óÌÚ†úô–À8íš={Îž5GQ•ïãí†çù,Y¼¨¶¶ÖÂíŽ@;˜¢OŸ>÷MŸ²²!4„MS¿ùæÛÇ{ìÌ™ÓÖŸcc™þ³)++›¿`a6žÌóüë6¼øâúL–$†pÚ! <ÏÜ‡æµoß>óÌ)¥¢(nÛ¶íÏ/®¯©©±kktG Ò¦[·n£FßÖ½{w¿ßŸ–N¥” ‚à÷ùß{oë‡~øõ×lß‹Úh‹””´0`@ž=:vì$Bh­ax©áwB(ÇiªVUõíáÃ‡8°g÷î#1mÄhhÑ¢¤c§Ž­Z¶*((àrº®îäÉ“ÕÕÕ‡Œ]›íààààààààààààààààààààààààààà`'ÿ|º¢ endstream endobj 13 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 14 0 R >> endobj 14 0 obj << /Length 6472 >> stream 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg 0.933 0.933 0.933 RG 1.000 1.000 1.000 rg 34.016 34.016 543.969 723.969 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 34.766 713.165 Td /F1 28.5 Tf [(Trainers Report )] TJ ET q 180.000 0 0 61.500 397.234 695.734 cm /I4 Do Q BT 34.016 682.774 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(ID: 26 - )] TJ ET BT 71.364 682.774 Td /F2 10.5 Tf [(Sun 29th September 2013)] TJ ET BT 193.941 682.774 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [( - Trainer: des cooke )] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 34.016 652.459 242.150 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 40.016 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Label)] TJ ET 0.957 0.957 0.957 rg 276.166 652.459 301.819 27.263 re f 0.200 0.200 0.200 rg BT 282.166 661.512 Td /F3 10.5 Tf [(Content)] TJ ET 0.867 0.867 0.867 RG 0.75 w 0 J [ ] 0 d 34.016 652.459 m 276.166 652.459 l S BT 40.016 636.372 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(Course Date)] TJ ET 0.75 w 0 J [ ] 0 d 276.166 652.459 m 376.772 652.459 l S 0.75 w 0 J [ ] 0 d 376.772 652.459 m 477.378 652.459 l S 0.75 w 0 J [ ] 0 d 477.378 652.459 m 577.984 652.459 l S BT 282.166 636.372 Td /F1 10.5 Tf [(Sun 29th 0000027104 00000 n 0000033576 00000 n 0000033641 00000 n 0000034648 00000 n 0000040387 00000 n 0000046859 00000 n 0000046924 00000 n 0000047094 00000 n 0000047159 00000 n trailer << /Size 25 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 47307 %%EOF
```

Comment: If you remove the options from the `stream()` method does the PDF load as expected?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay I got sidetracked into a big project. If I remove excess and just have $dompdf->stream("sample4.pdf"); then it comes up as a download and displays as expected. Add in the ,array("Attachment"=>0) and it fails in the browser?

Comment: You said it leads to a page of text, what kind of text?

Comment: Hi Brian - I have edited original to add some at the bottom of post - this is not all the content. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What web browser are you using? The text you see is the actual content of the PDF document. Probably what is happening is that the content-type header is not correct or your browser doesn't know how to handle it. dompdf should be setting the correct content type, so first check that (usually you can see it by displaying the page info/properties.

Comment: OK google chrome - that makes sense - another project worked fine with google chrome but I was using codeignitr rather than slim etc. Can I get a link to learn how to correct the content type. I just tried in in IE and it was fine?!

Comment: As I said, dompdf *should* be setting the content type when you call the `stream` method. So first you should check the page properties to see if the current content-type is correct. Your browser's developer tools can help get that info. If you have a URL I can take a look.

Comment: Hi Brian - I feel we are getting closer and am very thankful for the help. The download url http://7214.co.uk/report/pdf/26 and one that has attachment set to zero. http://7214.co.uk/report/pdfA/26 Again I have got it to work in IE both ways and usually use chrome. Much appreciated.

Comment: So something on your system appears to be modifying the header produced by dompdf. Even the download version is returned with the incorrect mime type. Both come back as `text/html`, which is why Chrome displays the PDF source instead of rendering it. IE is probably performing content type sniffing, looking at the source and deciding the document is actually a PDF despite the content type. If you have some kind of intermediate system that performs buffering or caching it could be mis-interpreting the content type.

Comment: I am using slim framework and the 'cache' => FALSE, and the doc starts as html "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>" I am unsure how to proceed - is there a tutorial I should read?

Comment: The issues is likely outside your template since it's probably not used, dompdf halts script execution when you call `$dompdf->stream()`. I'm not familiar with the slim framework so I can't say where the issue might be. If you can add more detail about the code flow it may help see the source of the issue.